# zip file download shows error symbols...using php code

Tags: php, download, zip

I have used a code for creating zip file form user checked checkbox files. I get the following error message:

> PK!Ýü•7f [Content_Types].xml ¢( ´TËnÂ0¼Wê?D¾V‰¡‡ªªú8¶H¥`ì
>   XõKöòúûnDUA*å)YïÌììÄƒÑÚšl 1iïJÖ/z,'½ÒnV²ÉK~Ï²„Â)a¼ƒ’m
>   ±Ñðúj0ÙHu»T²9bxà<É9X‘ ÀQ¥òÑ ¤×8ãAÈO1~ÛëÝqé‚Ãk6$N{9›êÍ+P9Y
>   ¢†vuÇGD²ìÃï»ÆoR€”wàÍ³¶
>   ÌIÊŠ~‰‰˜8›ïWòZè“"V0}¿˜ûßÀ»„´ù“>þÁŒýuQwHoî·áÿÿPK!‘·óN_rels/.rels ¢(
>   Œ’ÛJA†ïßaÈ}7Û "ÒÙÞH¡w"ë„™ìwÌ¤Ú¾½£ ºPÛ^æôçËOÖ›ƒ›Ô;§<¯aYÕ
>   Ø›`Gßkxm·‹PYÈ[š‚g GÎ°inoÖ/<‘”¡<Œ1«¢â³†A$>"f3°£\…È¾TºI S‘ÌõŒ«º¾ÇôWš™¦ÚY
>   igï@µÇX6_Ö]7~ fïØË‰ÈaoÙ.b*lIÆrj)õ,l0Ï%‘b¬
>   6ài¢ÕõDÿ_‹Ž…, ¡   ‰Ïó|uœZ^tÙ¢yÇ¯;!Y,}{ûCƒ³/h>ÿÿPK!Öd³Qú1word/*rels/document.xml.rels
>   ¢( ¬’ÍjÃ0„ï…¾ƒØ{-;ý¡„È¹”@®­ûŠ½þ¡²$´›¶~û
>   CR‡÷â‹`Fhæ“´›íwoÄ'êœU%)´¥«:Û(x/vwÏ ˆµ­´qH°Íoo6¯h4ÇCÔvžDL±¤
>   eök)©l±×”86îÔ.ôš£ôºüÐ ÊUš>É0Í€ü"Sì+a_Ýƒ(›ÿÏvuÝ•øâÊc–¯TÈ/<¼!s¼ÅXd3‰´
>   ¯ƒ¬–¡?'g![?óü4ê¹úÇ%ë9Žþ¶RŽk6Çð°$Cí,ú`&gë!/=ÿÿÿPK!æ“KxîQword/document.xmlœTÛnÛ0}°0ôžØÉ²´5âë²îi@Ñv
>   È²-L‰Ž—}ý(*²lE‹`/’É#žC‘”7·?NÒ¶`‹yÆi”ÊÖûþ|?»fI@nK®ÁÊ‚e`·Û÷ï6]^‚h´˜…
>   ùÐÑåiD# spÒX7Éôuj¸ÿÑº™ã8ª½Ò
>   é2ËÖl¤‚µÞæ#ÅÌ(á!@…1$‡ªRBŽÛá/Ñ"wcÊ½bê¥¦À†F¹0±™ÿe£+6Éá­KŒžÎuîµÒóŽúaôv¾t„¼»<1.²·´ÇFŠSÄ%)ü­9eb¸²'š8ÿôÿÔ¼95/´ÓHõç"T‹-ÍÒÊcÜ]Òå4‹åcÁ²ìn±Î¾Ü°Éµ“o5FäwŸûHÃpû,R5×zA&4s4Ö¶¤
>   ½”    Gäq*ÑnÒx>®J«{¡;²¿®›Æ
>
> > øéÐYV£ë‰ðè]/¯îoV}®®~úEhGm¹\ÑSëò†¾?^ÓwÏéêo$ùãûÿ©«×îÇ!)OÚ^ýrÍC$ñy@“°íÝö/­yH*œ˜ñ„´½)‘Þµ÷ß»Š×UDb‚`}"×qÛ‹”J×—–¤ÃX^æ)I`nÌEŒ¼Šp)øèÆli¹V[]Š1M<”àÈÞ©OÐP“ô6râ=¯‰’zÀgb
> >     Ig…ÁuSÙ

Here is my code:

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");// some browsers need this header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
filename=$archive_file_name"); 
header('Expires: 0'); header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); header('Pragma: public'); header("Content-Length:". " $zipped_size"); 
ob_clean(); flush(); 
readfile("$archive_file_name"); 
unlink("$archive_file_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't an error message, that's a zip file rendered as text.

Presumably, after you have generated the zip file, you are sending it to the browser with the wrong Content-Type. Possibly you are setting no Content-Type at all, so PHP will default to `text/html`.

The browser then gets something it is told is HTML and so it tries to render it as a webpage.

Set the correct content-type in your program:

```
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have used the below content-types header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");// some browsers need this
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Length:". " $zipped_size");
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("$archive_file_name");
unlink("$archive_file_name");